# Error en android studio con image-croper: No se pudieron resolver todos los archivos para la configuración ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: android, java-8, sdk

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en android studio of home, en la cual importo la librería *android-image-croper*. Al ejecutar la app me manda el error que escribiré pronto, pero cuando elimino o elimino las implementaciones la aplicación funciona normalmente, y realmente necesito esa implementación porque me permitirá modificar el tamaño de la imagen de los usuarios.

Este es el error que me envió:

> Causado por:
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: No se pudieron resolver todos los archivos para la configuración ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

1. el código que tengo en build.gradle (este es el del proyecto)

```
    buildscript {
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
    
        }
    }// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
        id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
    //    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.31' apply false
    }
    
    
    
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

2. el código que tengo en build.gradle (este es el módulo del proyecto)

```
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
    
    android{
        compileSdk 30
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.domiciliosblader"
            minSdk 19
            targetSdk 30
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
    
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }
    
    
    
    dependencies {
    
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.4'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.3'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:20.0.2'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
        implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
        implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
        //implementation 'com.github.jesseruder:Android-Image-Cropper:3.0.+'
    
    }
```

Comment: Sorry this stackoverflow is in spanish, pleas translate this question for your result.

Comment: listo bro, ya lo hice espero y puedan ayudarme

Comment: Esta ejecutando android studio mediante proxy? o algun firewall que lo pueda bloquear?

Answer (score 0):

Actualiza la librería a su ultima versión
`implementation 'com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.2.0'`
tambien agregas el multiDexEnabled en true esto hace que tu app compile y lea varios archivos DEX

tu configuracion quedaria de la siguente manera

```
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
    
    android{
        compileSdk 30
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.domiciliosblader"
            minSdk 19
            targetSdk 30
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled = true
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
   
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.4'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.3'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:20.0.2'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
        implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
        implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
        implementation 'com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.2.0'
}
```

Comment: bro primeramente te agradezco por ayudarme, pero despues de implementar lo que es has recomendad me sale el siguiente error: Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'MavenRepo' was added by build file 'app\build.gradle'

Comment: bro prueba quitando   allprojects {
            repositories {
                mavenCentral()
                maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
            }
        } sino lo configuras en el gradle principal